# Comparing a hash of arrays to an array to find similarities

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm trying to compare the selected animal_id array to the "animal_id" object in the owners_to_animals array so I can have a list of only the relevant owner_id's. I tried to iterate through the hash then only select the animal_id object that matches in the animal_id array but it prints out animal_id=20 which isn't part of the animal_id array.

```
animal_id = [23, 53, 63]
owners_to_animals = [
  { "owner_id" => 73, "animal_id" => 53 },
  { "owner_id" => 73, "animal_id" => 23 },
  { "owner_id" => 73, "animal_id" => 63 },
  { "owner_id" => 73, "animal_id" => 20 },
  { "owner_id" => 83, "animal_id" => 23 },
  { "owner_id" => 83, "animal_id" => 63 }
]

owners_to_animals.each do |x|
  # puts x
  # x.each do |y|
  for i in animal_id do
    # puts i
    if x.select { |a| a["animal_id"] == i }
      puts x
    else
      puts "no"
    end
  end

  # end

end
```

I'm confused as to why x returns:

```
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>53}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>53}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>53}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>23}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>23}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>23}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>63}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>63}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>63}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>20}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>20}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>20}
{"owner_id"=>83, "animal_id"=>23}
{"owner_id"=>83, "animal_id"=>23}
{"owner_id"=>83, "animal_id"=>23}
{"owner_id"=>83, "animal_id"=>63}
{"owner_id"=>83, "animal_id"=>63}
{"owner_id"=>83, "animal_id"=>63}
```

Comment: I edited your code for formatting, and also made `owners_to_animals` an explicit array, as your original code was slightly confusing.

Comment: `owners_to_animals.select { |o_a| animal_id.include? o_a['animal_id'] }`

Comment: @mudasobwa That's exactly the answer I posted 3h before your comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select` will return an empty array if nothing matches, which in Ruby is a "truthy" value, so the `else` branch of your code never gets executed.

```
if []
  puts "true"
else
  puts "false"
end
# Outputs "true"
```

What you want to achieve can be done in a single line:

```
puts owners_to_animals.select { |x| animal_id.include?(x["animal_id"]) }
# Output:
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>53}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>23}
{"owner_id"=>73, "animal_id"=>63}
{"owner_id"=>83, "animal_id"=>23}
{"owner_id"=>83, "animal_id"=>63}
```

Comment: In similar situations where the array `animal_id` and/or `owners_to_animals` is/are large, it may be advisable to first convert the former to a set: `require 'set'; animal_id_set = animal_id.to_set; owners_to_animals.select { |x| animal_id_set.include?(x["animal_id"]) }`. Set lookups are very fast when compared to stepping through an array, which is done for every element (hash) of `owners_to_animals`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Wouldn't the conversion to set cost the difference anyway?

Comment: It's a comparatively small one-time cost (basically turning the array into a hash with the array elements as keys and `nil` as values for O(1) lookup), as opposed to O(n) lookups each time, which can be problematic if `animal_id` is large.